# Why keras Tokenizer with unknown token requiring embedding's input_dim to be vocab_size +2, instead of vocal_size+1

Tags: python, keras, nlp, tokenize, embedding

I am working with keras embedding and using Keras tokenizer. At first, I wasnt using oov_token (for unknown token) and I was having length of my tokenizer's `word_counts` as `54`.

For embedding I used to give `my_tokenizer.word_counts+1` as `input_dim`, later I had a need to tackle unknown tokens, so I change my code to following

```
my_tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token="<UKN>") # First it was Tokenizer()    
my_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(my_tokens)
my_sequences = module_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(my_tokens)
```

But after adding the unknown token (which got index 1 as `{'<UNK':1,..}` ) with `my_tokenizer.word_counts+1` as `input_dim`, I got error for index like

```
55 not in indices [0,55]
```

My word_count(`my_tokenizer.word_counts+1`) is `55` (one extra than last(54) approach without unkonwn token).

Now if I add `2` in my vocabulary size (`my_tokenizer.word_counts`) it works fine

```
layers.Embedding( my_tokenizer.word_counts+2 , ... )
```

but I dont understand why I need to add 2 (make it `56`)

I would be very thankful for the help

Answer (score 2):

You need to add +2 for the OOV token, as you mentioned, and also the padding.

Comment: You answer gave me hint and I realised that I am using `len(my_tokenizer.word_counts)` which was only giving `54` as <UNK> had no count, so pretty stupid of me,